# Assign a consistent random number to id in SAS across datasets

Tags: random, sas

I have two datasets `data1` and `data2` with an `id` column. I want to assign a random id to each id, but this random number needs to be consistent across datasets. (`rand_id` for `id=1` must be the same in both datasets). The objective is to get:

| id | rand_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.4212 |
| 2 | 0.5124 |
| 3 | 0.1231 |

| id | rand_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.4212 |
| 3 | 0.1231 |
| 2 | 0.5124 |
| 4 | 0.9102 |

Note that Id's do not need to be ordered, and some Id's might appear in one dataset but not at the other one. I thought

```
DATA data1;
SET data1;
CALL STREAMINIT(id);
rand_id=RAND('uniform');
RUN;
```

and the same for `data2` would do the job, but it does not. It just takes as seed the first id and generates a sequence of random numbers.
From the STREAMINIT documentation, it seems it's only called once per data setp. I'd like to be called it in every row. Is this possible?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Solved:

```
DATA data1;
SET data1;
seed = id;
CALL RANUNI(seed,rand_id);
DROP seed;
RUN;
```

Generates the desired result.

Comment: What happens when ID is character?  Character ID is much more common.  I would make a lookup table of ID and RAND_ID.

Comment: Definitely do NOT seed the random number from the ID - that means it's not random anymore!

Comment: I know, I just want it to be consistent across datasets so rand_id is not ordered in any way.

Comment: Using ranuni in this way is not fundamentally different from ordering by id or sqrt(id) or similar - it's just applying a formula to ID.  It's not random, and the order does have a relationship to the original ID value.  Don't do this.  Use one of the other options here, all of which will work for your needs and most of which are quite fast to run (not significantly slower than this).

Comment: Id's are given to me, and I don't know if there is an inherent order or not (maybe id's are ordered by the order they get into the dataset). Randid avoids that.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to create a table `random_values` with an associated random id for each id that we later join on the two tables.

```
*assign random seed;
%let random_seed = 71514218;

*list of unique id;
proc sql;
create table unique_id as
select distinct id
from (
select id from have1
union all 
select id from have2
)
;
quit;

*add random values;
data random_values;
set unique_id;
call streaminit(&random_seed.);
rand = rand('uniform', 0, 1);
run;

*join back on have1;
proc sql;
create table have1 as
select t1.id, t2.rand as rand_id
from have1 t1 left join random_values t2
on t1.id = t2.id
;
quit;

*join back on have2;
proc sql;
create table have2 as
select t1.id, t2.rand as rand_id
from have2 t1 left join random_values t2
on t1.id = t2.id
;
quit;
```

Comment: Indeed, but this works as long as id's are ordered. I think if they are not as in the example, this method does not work.

Comment: Your answer is good too, but in my case I have many id's so do the merge seems too costly. After several attempts, I think I got it! Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a lookup dataset.  You could create/update it using HASH object.

First make an empty dataset:

```
data rand_id;
  set one(keep=id);
  rand_id=.;
  stop;
run;
```

Then process the first dataset.  Adding the new RAND_ID variable to that dataset and also populating the RAND_ID dataset with all of the unique ID values.

```
data one_random;
  if _n_=1 then do;
    declare hash h(dataset:'rand_id');
    rc=h.definekey('id');
    rc=h.definedata('id','rand_id');
    rc=h.definedone();
  end;
  if eof then rc=h.output(dataset:'rand_id');
  set one end=eof;
  if h.find() then do;
    rand_id=rand('uniform');
    rc=h.add();
  end;
  drop rc;
run;
```

Repeat for any other datasets that share the same ID variable.

```
data two_random;
  if _n_=1 then do;
    declare hash h(dataset:'rand_id');
    rc=h.definekey('id');
    rc=h.definedata('id','rand_id');
    rc=h.definedone();
  end;
  if eof then rc=h.output(dataset:'rand_id');
  set two end=eof;
  if h.find() then do;
    rand_id=rand('uniform');
    rc=h.add();
  end;
  drop rc;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to do this in my opinion is to create a format dataset.  Tom's hash example is fine also, but this is probably easier if you don't know hash tables.

Do NOT seed the random number from the ID itself - this is not random anymore.

```
data forfmt;
  set data1;
  call streaminit(7);
  label = put(rand('Uniform'),12.9);
  start = id;
  fmtname = 'RANDIDF';
  output;
  if _n_ eq 1 then do;
    hlo='o';
    label='.';
    output;
  end;
run;

proc format cntlin=forfmt;
quit;
```

Then you can use `put(id,randidf.)` to assign the random ID (and use `input` instead of `put` and make it an informat, if you want it to be numeric, that's handled via `type='i';` and needs the input to be character or turned into character via `put`).  No sorting required, very fast lookup most of the time.